# Is that correct that "make prefix" overwrites ./configure --prefix?

Tags: makefile

I would like to understand whether

```
./configure --prefix = /usr/abc && make install
```

has the same effect as

```
./configure && make prefix=/usr/abc install
```

In particular, is it correct that `make prefix` overwrites `./configure --prefix`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's correct (assuming your project is using automake or your `Makefile.in` is compatible with automake behavior).  This is really more of an autoconf / automake question than a makefile question.

When you run ./configure it will generate a Makefile and that makefile will contain a variable:

```
prefix = /usr/local
```

and the paths in the makefile will use the make variable `$(prefix)` to compute the destination paths.

If you run `./configure --prefix=/usr/abc` then the generated Makefile will contain a variable:

```
prefix = /usr/abc
```

instead.

Then if you run `make prefix=/foo/bar`, the command line setting of variables overrides the Makefile setting (this is standard behavior always for make regardless of makefile).

Note the difference however: with `./configure --prefix=...` the makefile contains the setting `...` so it's always the default unless you override it.  If you run `make prefix=...` then the value of `prefix` is set to `...` *only for that invocation of make*.  If you run it again as just `make` without overriding `prefix` on the command line, it will go back to the default.

Comment: While this works, I would still avoid it if possible. Configure may also generate additional files, not necessarily Makefiles, where it can replace tokens with configured values (including prefix). This way resulting application may have some locations incorrect, depending on how it is written.

Comment: What is "this" that you are talking about?  What are you trying to avoid?  I certainly agree that it's possible for people to mis-write their Makefile.in / configure.ac files to not correctly respect `prefix`... indeed that happens all the time because getting this stuff right is tricky.  But that's the way it is with tools that need to be very flexible... and configure and install tools need to be maximally flexible to accommodate all the different end-user requirements.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough. I don't disagree that you can override prefix on `make` invocation, I just wanted to point out that `configure` may also generate other files or config headers which will not necessarily be updated by `make`, so basically I would consider specifying prefix at `configure` time instead of compilation time.

Comment: True, although a well-formed tool will not have this problem because it implies that paths are hardcoded into the package, which is always a bad idea.  Packages should strive to be fully relocatable.  Obviously this is a QoI issue and you don't always get what you want.